# How to extract common nodes from list of lists with order preserved and starting from most frequent nodes to less frequent nodes

Tags: list, python-2.7

```
[[0, 11, 1, 27, 29, 5],
[0, 11, 1, 118, 52, 31, 89, 113],
[0, 11, 1, 118, 52, 51, 47],
[0, 11, 1, 118, 52, 89, 42, 43, 4, 109],
[0, 11, 46, 39, 33, 54]]
```

The desired output is :

```
[[0, 11],
[0, 11, 1],
[0, 11, 1, 118, 52]]
```

keeping the order

Comment: Why is the output three lists if different length?

Comment: You need to make clear the meaning of "common nodes."

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of your code and explain clearly what the problem with it is. If you haven't written any, start by doing that.

Comment: I want to get sub lists  with common nodes from the bigger list.As you can see in the main list of lists, the node [0,11] is present in all the 5 lists and then [0,11,1] is present in 4 lists and [0,11,1,118,52] is present in 3 lists.
@John1024 what i meant by common nodes is that the extracted nodes must be in the correct sequence e.g should be 0,11 and not 11,0.